# How to make values in the audit logging plugin readable to meer mortals?

Tags: grails

And by mere mortals, I'm referring to users of the system(non developers). The audit logging plugin is beautiful but one thing that bothers me is I can't quite customize it for our client. For instance instead of showing a table of what fields were changed etc. I'd like to turn it to sentences that can easily be read by ordinary humans. Problem is, how do i do that with eventlisteners? The example in the description does what i want i just dont know yet how to pass it to the controller and show it in the gsp. I cant show you somr sample codes as i am on the phone right now. So maybe later when i get back home. *sorry* any ideas how i can implement it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did something like this not by changing the way the plugin recorded the changes, but by creating a TagLib that read from the audit logging objects to show history.  Then place the TagLib on any page you want to show history and pass it an object id.

```
//Import into your TagLib
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.orm.auditable.AuditLogEvent


//Basic TagLib idea
def objectHistory = {attrs->
    if(attrs.persistedObjectId) {
        def events = AuditLogEvent.findAllByPersistedObjectId(attrs.persistedObjectId, [sort:"dateCreated",order:"desc"])
        if(events.size() > 0) {
          events.each{event->
            out << event.propertyName
            out << ' changed on '
            out << event.dateCreated
            out << 'The old value was '
            out << event.oldValue
            out << ' and the new value is '
            out << event.newValue
          }
        }
    }
}
```

And lets say you had a page that showed information about a company:

```
<g:objectHistory persistedObjectId="${companyInstance.id}" />
```

You could get pretty creative about how you had the TagLib show the data, ignore certain events, show who made the change (`event.actor`), etc.

Comment: I see.. thank you for answering. The persisted objects in the database were really ok but i was looking for something more readable. Our users are oldies and they had complaints about it. Anyhow I'll study this approach and see how it goes. Thank you so much answering.